# VS2008 IDE giving 5 second latency when switching tabs between aspx and aspx.cs , how come?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, latency

I have VS2008 (SP1)  installed on a XP sp2 laptop.

One thing weired on IDE, I don't know how to fix it.

I'm programming a web application, have many tabs openning at the same time. When I switch from aspx to aspx.cs back and forth, I always get about 5 seconds delay before I can type the keyboard.

I thought this might relate to some background layout rendering process, but I never open "Design" screen fro aspx page, I always open "Source" screen. This 5 seconds delay annoying a lot.

Any configurations? suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/49ab7810-f298-413b-8c9f-a060b04f71fe/) can be of any help, which seems to suggest that it's the HTML validation that's making the switch horribly slow.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio really likes a good video card with a decent amount of video memory.  It uses this for compositing the webpage.

Also, it's just a resource hog in general.

Answer (score 0):

How close are you to using all your physical RAM on your machine?  Additionally, how many other processes are running when you are doing this, e.g. do you have an anti-virus, a handful of auto-updaters(Microsoft, Apple, Java, HP drivers), services like Windows error reporting, SQL Server, etc. running?

It can be a resource hog as others have noted and if this is early in opening the program there may be background things like loading assemblies going on.